# What are the possible disadvantages of using this PNP transistor?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, mosfet-driver, pnp, igbt

I read this [application note](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-5073.pdf.pdf)  from Fairchild Semiconductors, and was wondering about what the possible disadvantages could be if a PNP transistor is used to bypass the Miller current as shown in the application note.

Would the increase of stray loop inductance be a possible problem since a PNP transistor will need some space to be put on the board, and that means the gate driver IC would be a bit further away from the main IGBT or MOSFET?

EDIT 1:-
This is the part from the document I was asking about:-

[image]

Comment: *Would the increase of stray loop inductance be a possible problem* Everything's possible and everything can be a problem. So what to do? **Quantify it**, that means, put some **numbers** on the issue and do calculations and/or simulations to prove that it is a problem or not. A track of 1mm has about 1 nH of inductance so you could make a guess what the inductance will be. Then simulate that and see if the inductance matters (make the inductance zero and compare that to a more realistic value). The faster you switch the more of an issue any inductance is going to be.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, Ah yes, so I have heard the comment: "Talk is cheap, show me the numbers". Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The faster switching might cause problems with the existing inductance in the source, dragging Vo below ground through Rg and killing the driver chip.